# How to tell if my web-host support https cUrl?

Tags: curl, hosting, php

I have been provided with the php info:

http://elfs.se/phpinfo.php

Theese are the instances that mention cUrl:

**configure command**

(...) '--with-curl' (...)

**cURL support** enabled

**cURL Information**    libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if can help, but try reading this [using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/)